# Can use ES2016 Proxies to trap the construction of a function but not a class

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to capture changes to the properties of a class instance during the construction of that class. To do that I am using an ES2016 Proxy to trap the constructor and return an instance of another Proxy.

I am able to produce an implementation that works as expected for Functions with a `this` context, but it does not work when applied to classes.

Syntactically, using it with a function looks like:

```js
function Bar(bla) {
  this.bla = bla
  setTimeout(() => this.bla = 'update 2', 1000)
}

// Returns a patched constructor that will log "updated"
// when a property on the instance is updated
const $Bar = ObservableConstructor(Bar) 
const bar = new $Bar('update 0')

bar.bla = 'update 1'
```

Where the implementation of `ObservableConstructor` is as follows:

```js
function ObservableConstructor(Ctor) {
  const instanceHandler = {
    set(target, key, value) {
      if (target[key] === value) return
      target[key] = value
      console.log('CHANGE:', key, value)
      return true 
    },
  }
  const constructorHandler = {
    construct(target, args) {
      const p = new Proxy(target, instanceHandler);
      target.apply(p, args);
      return p
    }
  };
  return new Proxy(Ctor, constructorHandler);
}
```

Essentially, I am able to `apply` the Proxy instance as the `this` context of the function, redirecting internal access of `this` to the proxy, trapping actions that set values on it.

This doesn't work when trying to pass in class constructors

```js
class Foo {
  constructor(bla) {
    this.bla = bla
    setTimeout(() => this.bla = 'update 2', 1000)
  }
}

const $Foo = ObservableConstructor(Foo)
const foo = new $Foo('update 0')

foo.bla = 'update 1'
```

Instead, it complains that

```
target.apply(p, args);
             ^
TypeError: Class constructor Foo cannot be invoked without 'new'
```

I am aware that I can't create an instance of a class without invoking the `new` keyword - but I have no idea how to instantiate a class where the `this` context is bound in the call.

Using `target.constructor.apply()` doesn't work and I am struggling to find a variation that does.

Any ideas on how I can solve this problem?

EDIT:

I have tried adjusting the implementation of `ObservableConstructor` to use `Reflect.construct` a number of ways without success

```js
const constructorHandler = {
  construct(target, args) {
    const p = new Proxy(target, instanceHandler);
    Reflect.construct(target, [], p)
    return p
  }
};
```

Comment: [`Reflect.construct`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Reflect/construct)

Comment: @JonasWilms I have updated my post with an implementation using `Reflect.construct` but I wasn't able to get it working. Do I misunderstand how you intended it to be used?

Comment: What does "without success" mean?

Comment: This is not possible. The best you could get is an instance with a proxy in its prototype chain.

Comment: "*I'm trying to capture changes to the properties of a class instance during the construction of that class*" - why? What underlying problem are you trying to solve by that? And can't you get the class to cooperate? It would be trivial with `class Foo extends Observable …`.

Comment: @Bergi here is the issue I am trying to solve, though I have been approaching it from different angles. I can't have the base class extend the proxy implementation as it's not allowed to know that it's being observed. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64715536/how-to-capture-proxy-set-actions-from-a-class-constructor

Comment: That's basically the exact same question (and Jonas just now has given pretty much same answer as I would have), but what I was wondering is *What do you need this for?*. Are you building a testing framework? A debugger? Which concrete library constructor do you want to observe, and why is it not allowed to know that it is being observed? (Which is really really hard, I think it's impossible to make this undetectable)

Comment: I think this question is asking for the same question as the second one, that's why I closed this one as a duplicate, as I think you narrowed down the problem much better in the other thread ...