# How to capture Proxy "set" actions from a class constructor?

Tags: javascript

How do I trap actions where a property is set from inside a constructor?

```js
class Foo {
  constructor() {
    setTimeout(() => this.value = 'value', 1000)
  }
}

const foo = new Foo()

const $foo = new Proxy(foo, {
  set(target, key, value) {
    if (target[key] === value) return
    target[key] = value
    console.log('Set', key, value)
    return true
  }
})
```

While here I am directly referencing `Foo`, in reality the `Proxy` implementation is inside a function with no knowledge of `Foo`, conversely `Foo` has no knowledge that it will be proxied. The solution should allow the usage of any class to be proxied, eg

```
const foo = new (ProxyWrapper(Foo))()
const bar = new (ProxyWrapper(Bar))()
const foobar = new (ProxyWrapper(Foobar))()
```

Answer (score 2):

You could create a Proxy on the prototype of the class:

```js
class Foo {
  constructor() {
    setTimeout(() => this.value = 'value', 1000)
  }
}

const Trap = Object.assign(function() {},  { 
  prototype: new Proxy({}, {
    set(target, key, value) {
      target[key] = value;
      console.log("Set", target, key, value);
      return true;
    },
  }),
});

const $Foo = function () {
  return Reflect.construct(Foo, [], Trap);  
}

const foo = new $Foo();



setTimeout(() => console.log(foo), 1100)
```

As a function injecting the trap that could be written as:

```js
function TrapMe(Super) {
  function Trapped() {
    return Reflect.construct(Super, [], Trapped); 
  }
  
  Trapped.prototype = new Proxy(Object.create(Super.prototype), {
    set(target, key, value) {
      target[key] = value;
      console.log("Set", target, key, value);
      return true;
    }
  });
  return Trapped;
}

const Foo = TrapMe(class Foo {
  constructor() {
    console.log("constructed");
    setTimeout(() => this.value = "value", 1000);
  }
});

new Foo();
```